# Conditional formatting random selection

Tags: excel

I've got a project where I need to randomly select some case files to do an audit. I want to make a random selection of case files for a specific employee doing a specific task (Employees are identified in a COlumn A and tasks are identified in Column B).

I found the following formula, but it is not exactly what I want:

`=INDEX(A$2:A$100,LARGE(IF(B$2:B$100="Task",ROW(B$2:B$100)-ROW(B$2)+1),INT(RAND()*COUNTIF(B$2:B$100,"Task")+1)))`

The above formula just returns one random name from Column A, based on Task chosen. I just want rows to be highlighted so that I can identify the case files, so I want to structure this as a formula for Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Do you have any criteria for the random sampling you wish to share? How many samples do you want per task? Need a method before you can conditionally format

Comment: there are 6 employees, and about 7-8 distinct tasks they can perform. I would like to pull 20-25 random samples per employee per task

Answer (score 0):

You can alter oneCellPaintedPer to get you whatever percentage you want. If you want one out of five to be highlighted put 5, one out of three, 3 etc etc

```
Sub generateRandoms()
    Dim rngOne                  As Range
    Dim rngTwo                  As Range
    Dim rngThree                As Range
    Dim rngFour                 As Range
    Dim arr()                   As Variant
    Dim counter                 As Long
    Dim rng                     As Range
    Dim cell                    As Range
    Dim oneCellPaintedPer       As Long

    oneCellPaintedPer = 5

    Set rngOne = Range("A1:A25")
    Set rngTwo = Range("B1:B25")
    Set rngThree = Range("C1:C25")
    Set rngFour = Range("D1:D25")

    arr = Array(rngOne, rngTwo, rngThree, rngFour)

    For counter = 0 To UBound(arr())
        Set rng = arr(counter)
        For Each cell In rng
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, oneCellPaintedPer) Mod oneCellPaintedPer = 0 Then
                cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
            Else
                cell.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End If
        Next cell
    Next counter
End Sub
```

[image]